# Native XML Databases with .NET

Tags: .net, xml, database

Are there any native XML Databases (That are free and preferably open-source) that work well with .NET

Comment: XML is a great tool for data exchange and import/export, but it's really not well suited as a database.

Comment: @Marc - erm, hmm... generically you're right, but that doesn't mean that it isn't an appropriate solution to some problems - if you're going to make that comment you need to qualify it with a question (i.e. why do you want a native XML database for your project) - clearly its not a concept entirely without merit: http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/XMLDatabaseProds.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does LINQ to XML count?

Answer (score 0):

You could use eXist-db (http://exist.sourceforge.net/) and access it using its REST or SOAP interface. Native .NET Applications are most likely commercial.